# Mef compose parts for all classes present in an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, mef

```
public class ClassMerger
{         

    [Import(typeof(ITest))]
    public ITest pTest { get; set; }

    [Import(typeof(INewTest))]
    public INewTest ObjImportClass { get; set; }

    private AggregateCatalog catalog { get; set; }
    public static CompositionContainer container { get; set; }

    public void Compose()
    {
        DirectoryCatalog dc = new DirectoryCatalog(@" Debug");
        catalog = new AggregateCatalog(dc);
        AssemblyCatalog catalog1 = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog1);
        container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);             
        container.ComposeParts(catalog);
    }        
}
```

In the above code when i say **container.composeparts(catalog)** all my interfaces(e.g., ITest) are null. 
But when i rewrite it as  **container.ComposeParts(this)** the parts are composed. If so how do i mention my container to compose parts for all the classes which are present in my assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You get null because it will never try to compose for your class **ClassMerger**, but rather for **AssemblyCatalog**, elaborating:

When you say **container.Composeparts(catalog);** you are telling MEF to compose parts for decorated properties inside your instance of *AssemblyCatalog*.

On the other hand, when you tell **container.ComposeParts(this);** you are telling MEF to compose those decorated properties on the instance of the class *ClassMerger*, thus finally finding your properties to fill in.

Note that by ***container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);*** you are telling MEF *where* to look for parts that may satisfy your later-to-load, decorated properties when you fire **.ComposeParts**...